# Rails where method with array parameter - example from a book, not clear to me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter, activerecord

I'm reading the book '**Beginning Rails 6 - From Novice to Professional**' (awesome book, btw), and I'm on a chapter about Advanced Active Record, great information, but one part of the text is driving me crazy, it works, but I don't get the explanation, could someone please clarify it to me?

> As in a regular `where` method, you can use arrays as parameters. In fact, you can chain finder methods with other named scopes. You define the recent scope to give you articles recently published: first, you use the `published` named scope, and then you chain to it a where call

To me, the code example isn't exactly what text says (I've tried to find any erratas, with no success):

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord validates :title, :body, presence: true
belongs_to :user has_and_belongs_to_many :categories has_many :comments

scope :published, -> { where.not(published_at: nil) }
scope :draft, -> { where(published_at: nil) }
scope :recent, -> { where('articles.published_at > ?', 1.week.ago.to_date) }

def long_title
"#{title} - #{published_at}"
end end
```

I don't see the `You define the recent scope to give you articles recently published: first, you use the published named scope, and then you chain to it a where call`, plus, can't I just use `scope :recent, -> { where('published_at > ?', 1.week.ago.to_date) }` instead `scope :recent, -> { where('articles.published_at > ?', 1.week.ago.to_date) }` **removing the `articles` from the `where`**?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what the text tries to say are two things.
One is that you can use arrays in `where` and active record understands and translates it properly to SQL. For example `Article.where(user_id: [1,2,3])` will find all articles where the `user_id` is either 1, 2 or 3.

The second thing they try to explain is that you can chain scopes. So in this case, what they try to explain is that you can do this: `Article.recent.published` or `Article.recent.draft`

For your last question, yes you can write it like you suggest and it would work `:recent, -> { where('published_at > ?', 1.week.ago.to_date) }`. The reason they use `articles.` is to ensure the scope works when you try to chain scopes with joins.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @TTD! I understood your points, although the last one wasn't so clear to me, but maybe it will be soon, as I keep reading... Thanks again!